# Path shows only related dependent picklist values of the controlling field

Tags: lightning-web-components, field-dependencies, pathassistant, path-optimizer, path

Can we create custom Path component on dependent picklist. The path should show only available value in the dependent picklist. Values can be changed on selection of controlling field.

Let say, if controlling field is 'A' dependent picklist field values is ['1', '2']. So in this case for any record controlling field is 'A'. The Path only should show '1', '2'.

If controlling is selected 'B' dependent values will be ['3','4']. So in this case for any record controlling field is B. The Path only should show 3, 4. It will vary on what you choose in the controlling and dependent field.

Answer (score 0):

I can hardly imagine having dependencies of the kind on the path.
The path can be based on the record type which is based on a Support/Sales process.

For ex, on the Sales process you define the allowed stage statuses, I don't see any standard way of adding a dependency.

Maybe try to handle your requirement with record types instead of dependencies.